# Where to put global html/css files in Django (Navbar.html, general.css, etc...) so that it's referable by all apps?

Tags: django

1) I want my project to be able to call `{% include navbar.html %}` from every template but I'm not sure where I'm supposed to place `navbar.html`. I tried placing it in `mysite/templates/navbar.html` but calling `{% include navbar.html %}` just gave me a `TemplateSyntaxError`.

2) I also want to be able to have a `general.css` referable by all of my apps. Is placing it in `mysite/static/general.css` a good idea?.

Comment: You need to use quotes for the included templates - `{% include "navbar.html" %}`

Comment: Thanks Iain! It still errors out for me though because my referencing html file is within `myapp/templates/` while `navbar.html` is within `mysite/templates/`. Do you know how I can reference there?

Comment: Can you show your settings.py file? And the template where you're trying to include.

Comment: Which part of my `settings.py` would you like to see?

Comment: The `TEMPLATES` setting would be a good start

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for the help but I just figured it out! Turns out what I really needed to do was extending htmls with the `{% block %}` tag. Everything works perfectly now. Sorry for wasting your time. For what it's worth though, my `TEMPLATES` is just the boilerplate that comes when starting a new project. Thanks again!